# Blank lines when reading CSV file in Java

Tags: java, android, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been working on this app in Android for a while now and suddenly encountered the following issue even though it has not been a problem many times before.

I am reading a CSV file in Java, but when I print a log of each line of that CSV file, there appears to be a blank line even though there is not one in the actual CSV file.

This is how I'm reading the file:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
try {
    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("My_file.csv"));
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(inputStreamReader);
    inputStream.nextLine(); // Ignores the first line
    while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = inputStream.nextLine(); // Gets a whole line
        String[] line = data.split(","); // Splits the line up into a string array

        array.add(line[1]);
    }
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run it, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and after putting in a log message before `array.add(line[1])` which printed the line, I found that there was a blank line in my CSV file (and there wasn't when I checked it).

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the part of the csv file that causes this error please..

Comment: i think you answering your question - it's a empty line in your file. And when you trying to split it with ",", you obviously have array with only 1 element. Have your read that article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All:

`array.add(line[1])` is going to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` every time you have a line without a `,` ... Might be a good idea to check for that before trying to read it. i.e. `if(line.length > 1) { array.add(line[1]);}`

Just doing this will fix multiple errors for you.